# android Dialog Boxes and differences

Tags: android

This might be an old question. but still I couldn't find satisfactory answer.
what is the difference between AlertDialog, AlertDialog.builder ,Dialog in Android. which one should I use?

Comment: You've got to give a bit more information, particularly about your research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html),

The **Dialog** class is the base class for dialogs, but you should avoid instantiating Dialog directly. Instead, use one of the following subclasses:

- AlertDialog
- DatePickerDialog or TimePickerDialog

---

**AlertDialog** allows you to show a dialog above your activity/fragment. It is usually used for prompting user for interaction including few buttons or notifying for something. **Dialog** class is the super class for this.

---

**AlertDialog.Builder** is an *inner static class* of **AlertDialog** which allows you to quickly setup a dialog with its handy methods

- `AlertDialog.Builder(Context context)`-->
  Creates a builder for an alert dialog that uses the default alert dialog theme.
  The default alert dialog theme is defined by alertDialogTheme within the parent context's theme.
- `AlertDialog.Builder(Context context, int themeResId)` -->Creates a builder for an alert dialog that uses an explicit theme resource.
  The specified theme resource (`themeResId`) is applied on *top of* the parent context's theme. It may be specified as a style resource containing a fully-populated theme, such as `Theme_Material_Dialog`, to replace all attributes in the parent context's theme including primary and accent colors.
  To preserve attributes such as primary and accent colors, the `themeResId` may instead be specified as an overlay theme such as `ThemeOverlay_Material_Dialog`. This will override only the window attributes necessary to style the alert window as a dialog.

**Note**

The **AlertDialog** class allows you to build a variety of dialog designs and is *often* the only dialog class you'll need. There are three regions of an alert dialog Title , Content area , and Action buttons.

The **AlertDialog.Builder** class provides APIs that allow you to create an **AlertDialog** with above kinds of content, including a custom layout.

Understand the concept with this example

```
// 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

// 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog requirements
builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
       .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

// 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

**Dialog** is the super class for **AlertDialog**( *subclasses*), **AlertDialog.Builder** is *an inner static class* of **AlertDialog**

Answer (score 0):

Read the android Official [Dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) guide.